# Laravel 5: whereRaw escapes integer to string

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

What is the Laravel eloquent query for this:

```
select * from `jobs` where (
      400000 between min_salary and max_salary
            or
      600000 between min_salary and max_salary
 );
```

I tried the below eloquent query which encapsulates the integer to string

```
$min = 400000;
$max = 600000;
Job::whereRaw('
     ? between min_salary and max_salary
        or
     ? between min_salary and max_salary',
     [$min,$max]
)->get();
```

Also tried Casting and DB::Raw none of the options were worked as expected.

```
protected $casts = [
    'min_salary' => 'integer',
    'max_salary' => 'integer',
];

$min = 400000;
$max = 600000;
Job::whereRaw('
     ? between min_salary and max_salary
        or
     ? between min_salary and max_salary',
     [DB::Raw($min),DB::Raw($max)]
)->get();
```

I tried the below eloquent query works as expected but i have hard coded the query directly(Unsafe)

```
$min = 400000;
$max = 600000;
Job::whereRaw(
   $min.' between min_salary and max_salary 
     or
   '.$max.' between min_salary and max_salary'
)->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Job::where(function($query){
    $query->where('min_salary','<',400000);
    $query->where('max_salary','>',400000);
})->orWhere(function($query){
    $query->where('min_salary','<',600000);
    $query->where('max_salary','>',600000);
})->get();
```